# How to import and render this OBJ file with correct texture?

Tags: graphics3d, import, regions, mesh, textures

Here's the output of a 3D scan of a bike, I need to render it in color with the texture file provided. Here are the files:

```
texture = CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/320b51fd-8cc3-4dc9-9610-591e25096e3b"] (*Import["textured_ 0_v2.jpg"]*)
objTable = CloudGet["https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/71483c49-eca5-425b-a251-29e112f2adde"] (*Import["~/3Ddata.obj", "Table"]*)
```

I can import the obj, but I need to import the texture too:

```
Import["3Ddata.obj"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could manually import it and construct Graphics3D:

```
rawobj = 
  Association[
   Reap[Cases[
      objTable, {t : "v" | "vt" | "f" | "vn", rest__} :> 
       If[t === "f", 
        Sow[Transpose[(ToExpression@StringSplit[#, "/"] & /@ {rest})],
          t], Sow[{rest}, t]]], {"v", "vt", "vn", "f"}, Rule][[2]]];

(*texture = Import["textured_0_v2.jpg"];*)

Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[
  rawobj["v"], {Texture[texture], EdgeForm[], 
   Polygon[rawobj["f"][[All, 1]], 
    VertexTextureCoordinates -> (rawobj["vt"][[#]] & /@ 
       rawobj["f"][[All, 2]]), 
    VertexNormals -> rawobj["vn"][[#]] & /@ rawobj["f"][[All, 3]]]}]]
```

[image]
If you want to use VertexColors, then

```
rules = AssociationThread[
   Flatten[rawobj["f"][[All, 1]]] -> Flatten[rawobj["f"][[All, 2]]]];
vcolors = 
  ImageValue[texture, 
   rawobj["vt"][[Range[Length[rawobj["v"]]] /. rules, ;; 2]], 
   DataRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}];

Graphics3D[
 GraphicsComplex[
  rawobj["v"], {EdgeForm[], 
   Polygon[rawobj["f"][[All, 1]], 
    VertexNormals -> rawobj["vn"][[#]] & /@ rawobj["f"][[All, 3]]]}, 
  VertexColors -> vcolors]]
```

Comment: The first example has much more detail than the second it look like...